# Input Type Number Auto Update with comma

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a question trying to have the input field auto-add a comma on input for readability. E.g 123,456.

.toLocaleString() has been used to resolve the end result, but i need the comma displaying at the time of input also.

Thanks.

```
  const handleGrossIncomeChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setGrossIncome(value);
    if (resultShower === false){
    setResultShower(!resultShower);
    resultExport = resultShower;
    }
    else {
      return resultShower
    }
  
  };

 <div className="inputClass">
      <div className="input-group">
        <p>Gross Income {""}
          <span className="currency-input">
            <span className="currency-symbol">£</span>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="grossIncome"
              id="grossIncome"
              autoComplete="off"
              onChange={handleGrossIncomeChange}
              className="currency-value"
              placeholder="0.00"
            />
          </span>
        </p>

      </div>


<button type="submit" name="resultTester" onClick={handleClick}>click me </button>
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intl.NumberFormat Api](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=JavaScript&docset_name=JavaScript&path=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl.html&platform=javascript&repo=Main&source=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) like below:

```js
function formatCurrency(event) {

  let value = event.target.value;
  

  value = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  

  value = new Intl.NumberFormat('zh-CN', { style: 'currency', currency: 'CNY' }).format(value / 100);
  
  event.target.value = value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount" oninput="formatCurrency(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the input value contains "," (not a number), the input has to be of the text type.

```
  <input
    type="text"
    onChange={(e) => {
      const value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.value.replaceAll(",", ""));
      if (isNaN(value)) e.currentTarget.value = "0";
      else e.currentTarget.value = value.toLocaleString();
      setGrossIncome(value);
    }}
  />
```

(Tested in React v18.0, ES5)